# Fail in make (gmake)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a bunch of variables in my GNU Makefile, and users might change their values. I'd like the Makefile to fail before it starts executing if some of those values don't make any sense.

For example:

```
FOODIR=foo
BARDIR=bar
```

is okay, but if the user sets this to

```
FOODIR=foo
BARDIR=foo
```

I'd like the Makefile to fail. I'm looking for the right syntax to do this. Something like:

```
ifeq ($(FOODIR),$(BARDIR))
    exit 1;
endif
```

but that doesn't work. What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Makefiles are not shell scripts; you can't use shell commands like `exit`.

There is a GNU make function `$(error ...)` you can use (if your GNU make is recent enough):

```
ifeq ($(FOODIR),$(BARDIR))
    $(error FOODIR is the same as BARDIR: $(FOODIR))
endif
```

Comment: Duh, you are right, section 8.12 in the manual. https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Comment: Remember that the version of the manual on the website documents the current latest release (GNU make 4.1).  Your version might not have all the same features/behaviors, if it's older.  You should look at the manual that comes with whatever version of GNU make you have.